# print and echo commands from php - view when activated remotly for debugging purposes

Tags: php, json, linux, debugging

I have an app that use android json php and mysql setup. My question is:

In the php file i have various print and echo commands which i like to see their output in order to see what is going on.

The php file is in the web and my server is debian 7

How do i usually go about debugging the php and check the json statements?

What is the or some of the recommended ways. Excuse me for the no code example will edit it later when ill be infront of more capable device.

Comment: *How do i usually go about debugging the php and check the json statements?* Answer: just visit the URL with suitable parameters

Comment: You could write yourself a php file which will behave like the device that is calling your php file, so that it's calling the functions what so ever. Also you could do Unittests

Comment: Raptor: What are sutiable parameters? And b. I am calling it from android java environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by running php from the server with the php command. that gives much more detailed and accurate error messages

```
php fileuwanttocheck.php
```